# Installing Mercurial 1.5.1 on Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, apt, debian-lenny, mercurial

What's the easiest way to install Mercurial 1.5.1 on Debian Lenny? Can I safely install the package from the sid repository using apt-get, or should I compile it from the sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm; looks like [backports.org doesn't go newer than 1.3.1 right now](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mercurial&searchon=names&section=all&suite=lenny-backports).

Given that, the safest approach is to build from sid's source package (so you'll still have a debian-packaged binary, just one you built yourself); see http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-sourcehandling.en.html for a quick primer

If you've added the sid source repository to your sources list, you might also consider using `apt-get build-dep` to install the build-time dependencies, and `apt-get source` to download and unpack the sources themselves.

Comment: Okay thanks. It sounds pretty complicated, so I think I will just stick with the 1.3.1 version from backports for now.